# isolate real number in complex number in java

Tags: java, android, numbers, complex-numbers

There is a formula i need to use for my app : [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%2025%2b%28Sqrt%5B5-25%5D-%282Pi0.3%C2%B2%29/%28Pi10%C2%B2%29Sqrt%5B2%2a980%281%2b%28Pi10%C2%B2%29/%28Pi10%C2%B2%29%29%5Dt%29%C2%B2%20from%200%20to%2038)

the part Sqrt(5-25) , can be positive or negative , and of course when negative we got a imaginary part that java cant handle.

i've searched around to find a complex class to handle that , but found only basic operation (+-*/).

how can i solve this in java knowing i only need to get the real part ?(imaginary have no importance)

i precise that i develop on android platform

(i post on stack because it's concerning application in java , but if its belong to math.se , tell me)

Comment: I think it would throw some exception when it comes across a negative nor.. u can just handle it using try catch just by converting it to +ve nor and find its square root by usual way...

Comment: The real part is so real as imaginary, if not then you would be able to take two and send it to me via post office.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply compute verything before:

plot 25-20+((2Pi0.3²)/(Pi10²)Sqrt[2*980(1+(Pi10²)/(Pi10²))]t)² from 0 to 38

or

plot 25-20+((2*0.3²)/(10²)Sqrt[2*980(1+1)]t)² from 0 to 38

or

25 - 20 +  4 * 0.0000081 * 3920*t^2 from 0 to 38 (I have some factor wrong, but you get the idea)

just apply basic math to the constants and remove the middle (imaginary part)  after applying the 2nd binomic formula.

There is nothing to do with complex numbers.

Comment: thanks , i didn't simply realize that i could get the squareroot outside the scope of the pow2 .

Comment: if it has to be fast do as few computations as possible (e.g. dont write 1+(10²pi/10²pi) for 2), the easier the formula becomes the esier it becomes to optimize it

Comment: why this is working fo squareroot of negative number but not for positive (even if i don't need to do that for positive) ?

Answer (score 2):

Taking the Square root of a general complex number can be done with the basic arithmetic operations on real numbers (plus taking square root of reals): http://www.mathpropress.com/stan/bibliography/complexSquareRoot.pdf (one technique is to utilise De Moivre's theorem: Any complex number a + bi can be written as  `r(cos θ + i sin θ)` where

```
r = sqrt(a^2 + b^2),  cos θ = a/r, sin θ = b/r
```

**Update**: the formula `r(cos θ + i sin θ)`  is originaly due to Euler, whereas De Moivre's theorem is

```
(a + ib)ⁿ = rⁿ(cos nθ + i sin nθ)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confused about the math. Square root of -25 is square root of 25*(-1) and that is square root of 25 * square root of -1 and that is 5i. Real part of that number is 0.

If you want the 5, just check for the sign of the number to be "rooted" and change it if it is negative.

Comment: that's the square root of a negative real rather than a general complex number.

Comment: You are correct, but the formula says sqrt(5-25), which is i*sqrt(20).

Answer (score 0):

The square root of an integer is going to be an integer or a complex number whose real part is zero.  The real part of the square root of a negative integer is zero.  Always.

So ...

```
public double realPartOfSquareRoot(int i) {
    return (i > 0) Math.sqrt(i) : 0;
}
```

---

> But how I solve this?  If I replace the squareroot by 0, I don't get a good result.  Do I suppose the imaginary part do something on the real with the rest of the formula.

I expect that's so!  (The idea of discarding the imaginary part didn't make much sense to me ... but I assumed you had a sound reason to do this.)

The real answer is to find a Java library that will do complex arithmetic.  I've never needed to use it, but the first one to examine should be the [Apache Commons Maths](http://commons.apache.org/math/userguide/complex.html) library.

Comment: but how i solve this , if i replace the squareroot by 0 , i don't get the good result , so i suppose the imaginary part do something on the real with the rest of the formula

Answer (score 0):

It's not right to say that "Java can't handle it".  No language that returns a double from a square root can handle it, but if you have a `Complex` class it's not an issue.  Python has one built in; it's easy to write one in Java.